# Should I remove unnecessary `else` in `else if`?

Tags: c

Compare the two:

```
if (strstr(a, "earth"))     // A1
    return x;
if (strstr(a, "ear"))       // A2
    return y;
```

and

```
if (strstr(a, "earth"))     // B1
    return x;
else if (strstr(a, "ear"))  // B2
    return y;
```

Personally, I feel that `else` is redundant and prevent CPU from branch prediction.

In the first one, when executing A1, it's possible to pre-decode A2. And in the second one, it will not interpret B2 until B1 is evaluated to false.

I found a lot of (maybe most of?) sources using the latter form.
Though, the latter form looks better to understand, because it's not so obviously that it will call `return y` only if `a =~ /ear(?!th)/` without the else clause.

Comment: Would a compiler really generate that second snippet?  I would doubt it.

Comment: Why did you removed return from your code? It's fully changing question?

Comment: It's very confusing to make edits that change the meaning of your question so substantially when there have already been answers posted to a previous version. Namely, it makes those answers incorrect.

Comment: please roll back to 3-rd version of your question or correct this one. This version's question is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your compiler probably knows that both these examples mean exactly the same thing. CPU branch prediction doesn't come into it.

I usually would choose the first option for symmetry.

Comment: For const integer, yes, the compiler will optimize it away. But what if compare with strings? Most compilers won't even know match(a, "xyz") implies match(a, "x").

Comment: I don't quite follow. You're talking about the `else` clause that follows a block that `return` s, right? I don't see how the conditional expression matters there.

Comment: @谢继雷'Lenik, it's irrelevant. The compiler knows that you can get past first condition only if it's false since return would be executed otherwise, so else is implied anyway no matter what you write in the condition. I've just tested it with GCC, it generates the same code for both cases even with no optimizations.

Comment: @谢继雷'Lenik, now these two mean different things. If `a` is "earth" then in the first case both foo() and bar() will be executed, while in the second case only foo() will.

Answer (score 3):

(*The following answers the original version of the question.*)

Do you realize that the two code snippets are NOT semantically equivalent???

Consider what happens if `a` is "earth".

- The first snippet calls `foo()` and then `bar()`.
- The second snippet calls `foo()` and skips the `bar()` call.

And this explains why the generated machine code is different.  It has to be to implement the different semantics of the respective code fragments!

> Personally, I feel that else is redundant ...

Unfortunately, your feeling is incorrect.

Lesson - write your code simply and clearly and leave optimization to the compiler ... which is going to do a far more accurate job than you can achieve.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The snippets in the updated version of the question are now semantically identical, and the `else` is redundant.  However:

- any half decent optimizing compiler will generate identical code for the two snippets, and
- it is a matter of opinion (i.e. subjective) which of the snippets is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Use `else if` to **state your intentions clearly**. Code is meant to be read by **humans**.

Let the compiler optimize this, and don't worry about optimization until your code is 1) working 2) crystal clear 3) profiled (do this in that order). When doing step 3, you'll notice that the bottlenecks are not where you supposed they would be.

Any attempt to control branch prediction or whatever low level stuff is silly: compilers are very good at optimizing and they use sophisticated methods to yield a fast code on your particular machine.

Look at output from LLVM based compilers to see what I mean: sometimes  you can't even remotely understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

usually it's better to use the second way if you want to test exactly the condition for a, for the exact solution, to reduce the options for the var or const "a". if you write two separate if's you can get 2 different solutions.

for example in your situation with the exact conditions you have there let's say a= -2

```
A: if (a < 0)
    return x; // if -2 is less than 0 will return x and it stops.
else if (a < 100)
    return y; // 

B: if (a < 0)
    return x; // -2 is less than 0 so it will return x and passes to the next if statement;
 if (a < 100)
    return y; // -2 is also less than 100 and it will return y too
```

Comment: I've never seen a language that passes to the next `if` statement after a `return` statement.

Comment: Umm..  I've changed a lot to my question.

Comment: @谢继雷'Lenik: yeah you did.. after i posted my answer. @Cody Gray: i meant that he should know exactly what he wants from a code, exactly what he wants to return.

Comment: I think what you are talking about is a single `return` for each function. IMO, multiple returns in this situation is perfectly clear

Comment: Still doesn't make any sense. Code snippets "A" and "B" will do the same thing if a = -2. Both will return x and stop. The second will *not* pass to the next if statement in C (or any other language that I happen to know of).

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the `try { return true; } finally { return false; }` thing in java.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply write

```
char* str;

strstr(a, "ear")

if (str != NULL)
{
  foo();

  if(strstr(str, "earth") != NULL)
  {
    bar();
  }
}
```